# python3 type hinting different type on a parameter

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

Let's say that my function can accept parameter `b` to be either an int or a list

```
def foo_fun(a: int, b: ??)->int:
   if isinstance(b,list):
       do something
   else 
       do something else
```

How can i use type hinting with this particular setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to be describing [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union).

For example:

```
from typing import Union


def foo_fun(a: int, b: Union[int, list]) -> int:
   if isinstance(b, list):
       do something
   else 
       do something else
```

Comment: thanks sorry for my ignorance. i didn't know there was a module for type hinting support. Thanks